# Como carregar imagem padrão caso o src="" não encontre?

Tags: html, imagem

Existe alguma forma de carregar uma imagem padrão, usando apenas `HTML`, caso o primeiro `src=""` não encontre o arquivo?

```
<img src="ola_mundo.png" alt="Olá Mundo"> // Existe algum atributo para isso?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outros fallbacks mais simples que pode experimentar, com javascript:

```
<img src="imagem-nao-existe.png" onerror="this.src='fallback.png'">
```

Um exemplo no jsfiddle do @Randrade: https://jsfiddle.net/wts9e4xb/1/

```html
Sem error
<br>

<img src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/otnaydur/otnaydur1103/otnaydur110300040/9112843-Gold-coins-stack-over-scater-coins-Stock-Photo-bar.jpg" alt="Olá Mundo" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://logz.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stack-overflow-logo.png';"
>

<br>Com error
<br>

<img src="loading.gif" alt="Olá Mundo" onerror="this.src='http://logz.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stack-overflow-logo.png';" >
```

Com CSS (requer tamanho fixo):

```
<style>
.image {
     width: 620px;
     height: 480x;
}
</style>

<div class="image" style="background: url(foto-nao-existe.png), url(fallback.png)"></div>
```

Comment: Bom, mesmo usando JS acredito que ainda sim seja a melhor solução.

Answer (score 6):

Encontrei essa solução...

```html
<object data="https://img.com.br/no_existe.jpg" type="image/png">
  <img src="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1094/984405951_34580c3cb9.jpg" />
</object>
```

Nessa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-arribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-valid)