# colocar dois arquivos em uma <img>

Tags: html, img

existe a possibilidade de caso o primeiro arquivo estiver quebrado ou corrompido exibir o segundo arquivo? exemplo:

```
<img src="teste1.png" src2="teste2.png">
```

Comment: Sim, é possível.
A resposta pode ser vista aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167058/como-carregar-imagem-padrão-caso-o-src-não-encontre

Comment: muito obrigado! pelo que vi o "onerror" seria a solução...